# Unsafe builtin method was used, future builds will need to rebuild all pages - gatsby build

Tags: gatsby

I am facing this error during "gatsby build"

*warning Unsafe builtin method was used, future builds will need to rebuild all pages
warning WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.existsSync*

please check the picture and package details below..

[image]

***Package.Json***

```
 "gatsby": "^3.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-material-ui": "^3.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^5.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "storybook": "^6.2.8",
    "storybook-css-modules-preset": "^1.0.7",
    "typeface-roboto": "^1.1.13",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your cache by `gatsby clean`?

Comment: yes i tried.. but didnt work ..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by [`gatsby-plugin-material-ui`](https://github.com/hupe1980/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/issues/65) plugin. You can follow the stack trace of the warning discussion [here](https://github.com/hupe1980/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/issues/65).

The resolution is to update the `gatsby-plugin-material-ui` to `3.0.0` version.

In your case, try downgrading to `3.0.0` rather than using `3.0.1`. Remove your `node_modules` before each trial and remove your cache by `gatsby clean`.

Alternatively, you can try disabling the auto prefixing (not ideal solution):

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-material-ui`,
  options: {
    disableAutoprefixing: true,
  },
},
```